# Re-ordering table with pre-calculated sequence

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to order a table with a pre-calculated sequence.

So in the example below the 5 item would be moved to the first, then the third item would be second and so on.

I can't seem to manipulate `sort` to achieve this, is it possible using `sort`?

```
var seq = [5, 3, 2, 1, 4];

var table  = $('.table');
var rows   = $('tbody > tr', table); 

rows.sort( function(a, b){ 
    return 0;
});

rows.each(function(index, row){
     table.append(row);
});
```

Comment: You need to have something in the row itself to match with the `seq` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `sort`, just loop over the `seq` array, collecting the rows:

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  var seq = [5, 3, 2, 1, 4];

  var table = $('table');
  var rows = $('tbody > tr', table);

  var new_rows = [];
  $.each(seq, function() {
    new_rows.push(rows.eq(this - 1)); // subtract 1 because `eq()` is 0-based
  });
  $.each(new_rows, function() {
    table.append(this);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="button">Click to reorder</button>
```

Comment: Much appreciated! I refined it a little as I didn't actually need it in an array, `$.each(seq, function() { table.append(rows.eq(this-1)); });`

Comment: That won't work, because when you append the row to the table, that changes the position of all the rows after it.